# How to convert time in php into MYSQL date datatype

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I using date picker as shown below#

[image]

1. i want to convert the value inside the text box into mysql DATE data type.
2. an example, "3/3/2014" convert into "2014-03-03"
3. just give me an example how to convert is enough

   - additional information, i use php and java script ( date picker ) to run all of this

Answer (score 1):

You don't need php to do that, use MySQL function DATE_FORMAT

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(your_column_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS your_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

an easy php way would be the functions `strtotime()` and `date()`

example:

```
$input= "3/3/2014";
$output= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($input));
```

[strtotime php.net](https://www.php.net/strtotime)

[date php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php)